# Re-using community builder lightning components in custom components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder, napili

Community builder templates comes with some standard lightning component like in Napili template, under support category we have 'Ask Question'.

Is it possible to re-use 'Ask Question' in another custom lightning component? I know and have tried using a custom lightning component into another one but this is a pre-defined from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible as far as I have investigated .This can be added as an idea in IdeaExchange for the product team .

Comment: I added that as an idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEURQA2